# Auto resize textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use report with textbox (in Access 07) that should resize with length of text. I use the 'can resize' and 'can shrink' attributes. This mostly works, but on some computers the text box stay in 'original' size, as it appears on design view of the report.

I didn't find what could cause this, all computers have the same version of office (07), reinstalling office doesn't change anything?

So onto the questions. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Is there a way to adjust the size (height) of the textbox in report through access. Is there a way to determine the number of lines a text will take in some font and size other then dividing length of the string (using rich text) with some predetermined number.

Comment: It's odd that this wouldn't work on some computers. Do you perhaps use a font that isn't installed there? -- For calculating width/height see http://www.lebans.com/textwidth-height.htm but be warned: lots of complicated API code and stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the problem user's profile to make sure they have a printer installed? 
I know it sounds like a silly answer, but I've seen odd things happen in Access Reports when no default printer is defined